# make navigation transparent when on home page otherwise default

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a navigation in which I try to put two backgrounds
1. Transparent (Only show when a user at homepage)
2. Default Color(When a user visit other pages)

I try to solve this using javascript by checking up the address bar URL but then I realize that I am unable to catch the Home page URL.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Give the homepage it's own class or ID and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `document.location.pathname`. This returns everything after your domain name and ignores the hash (http://example.com/#hash) and the query string (?key=value&ke1=value1).
Here's an example

```js
// put here your homepage paths
var homepagePaths = ["/", "/index.php", "/index.html", "/index.htm"];

if(homepagePaths.indexOf(document.location.pathname) === -1) { // if the path is not the homepage
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.backgroundColor="#0e1623";
    // or
    // document.getElementById("navbar").classList.add("coloured-navbar");
}
```

Here you could just color the navbar or set a specific CSS class in which you specify text and background colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can add opacity 'OnClick' on other tabs.
use Css `opacity` to your homepage on click event.